# I'm using Pandas in Python and wanted to know how to split a value in a column and search that value in the column

Tags: python

Normally when splitting a value which is a string, one would simply do:

```
string = 'aabbcc'

small = string[0:2]
```

And that's simply it. I thought it would be the same thing for a `dataframe` by doing:

```
df = df['Column'][Range][Length of Desired value]

df = df['Date'][0:4][2:4]
```

Note: Every string in the column have the same length and are all integers written as a string data type

If I use the code above the program just throws the Range and takes [2:4] as the range which is weird.

When doing this individually it works:

`df2 = df['Column'][index][2:4]`

So right now I had to make a loop that goes one by one and append it to a new Dataframe.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you have a DataFrame with a column that has a value in string form and you'd like to add a column with a specific part of that string?

Comment: What aspect of this particular situation is not covered by the many existing resources on indexing and slicing? _If I use the code above the program just throws the Range and takes [2:4] as the range which is weird._ Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do the operation element wise, you can use `apply` (see [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)):

```
df['Column'][0:4].apply(lambda x : x[2:4])
```

When you did `df2 = df['Column'][0:4][2:4]`, you are doing the same as `df2 = df['Column'][2:4]`.

You're getting the indexes 0 to 4 of `df` and then getting the indexes 2 to 4 of that one.